# multiple plot outputs R in different tabs (shinyDashboard)

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

The code currently produces the dashboard and the side panels for the plots, it also produces one plot. (which ever is called first in the final line). If anyone has any suggestions on how to produce two separate plots on two different tabs using a shiny dashboard it would be much appreciated. Tearing my hair out!

https://lot1bct.shinyapps.io/lot1bct/

My current state, minus the "fuels" tab and second plot for reference on what i'm aiming for.

The code below has the second plot code mocked up along with the additional dashboard code in the "fuels" tab which the live version does not.

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- testData
fuelData <- fuelDataCSV
tyreData <- tyreDataCSV

ui <- dashboardPage(
skin="green",
dashboardHeader(title = "Strategy Dashboard v0.1",
              dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                           taskItem(value = 10, color = "green",
                                    "Documentation"
                           ),
                           taskItem(value = 30, color = "aqua",
                                    "UI"
                           ),
                           taskItem(value = 15, color = "yellow",
                                    "Data Developmentt"
                           )

              )),
## Sidebar content
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
  menuItem("Tyres", tabName = "tyres", icon = icon("circle-o")),
  menuItem("Fuels and Lubericants", tabName = "fuel", icon = icon("flask")),
  menuItem("Times", tabName = "times", icon = icon("clock-o")),
  menuItem("Documentation", tabName = "documentation", icon = icon("sticky-note-o")),
  menuItem("Downloads", tabName = "downloads", icon = icon("download")),

  # Custom CSS to hide the default logout panel
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-server-account { display: none; }'))),

  # The dynamically-generated user panel
  uiOutput("userpanel")
)
),
## Header Content


## Body content
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "home",

          h2("UI Tests"), p("This published version is the first test build (version 0.1).")
  ),

  # Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "tyres",
          h2("Tyre data sets"), fluidPage(

            sidebarPanel(

              sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size (Laps)', min=1, max=nrow(tyreData),
                          value=min(20, nrow(tyreData)), step=1, round=0),

              selectInput('x', 'X', names(tyreData)),
              selectInput('y', 'Y', names(tyreData), names(tyreData)[[2]]),
              selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(tyreData))),

              checkboxInput('density', 'Density'),
              checkboxInput('trend', 'Trend')


            ),

            mainPanel(
              plotOutput('plotT')
            )
          )
  ),

  # Third tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "fuel",
          h2("Fuel and Lubricant data sets"),

          fluidPage(

            sidebarPanel(

              sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size (Laps)', min=1, max=nrow(fuelData),
                          value=min(20, nrow(fuelData)), step=1, round=0),

              selectInput('x', 'X', names(fuelData)),
              selectInput('y', 'Y', names(fuelData), names(fuelData)[[2]]),
              selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(fuelData))),

              checkboxInput('density', 'Density'),
              checkboxInput('trend', 'Trend')


            ),

            mainPanel(
              plotOutput('plotF')
            )
          )
  ),

  # Fourth tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "times",
          h2("Times data sets")
  ),

  # Fifth tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "documentation",
          h2("Documentation")
  ),

  # Sixth tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "downloads",
          h2("Downloads")
   )
  )
 )
)

tyrePlot <- function(input, output) {

tyreData <- reactive({
     tyreDataCSV[sample(nrow(tyreDataCSV), input$sampleSize),]
})

output$plotF <- renderPlot({

p <- ggplot(tyreData(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()

if (input$color != 'None')
  p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)

if (input$density)
  p <- p + geom_density_2d()
if (input$trend)
  p <- p + geom_smooth()

print(p)

}, height=700)

}

fuelPlot <- function(input, output) {

  fuelData <- reactive({
     fuelDataCSV[sample(nrow(fuelDataCSV), input$sampleSize),]
  })

output$plotF <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(fuelData(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()

    if (input$color != 'None')
        p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)

    if (input$density)
        p <- p + geom_density_2d()
    if (input$trend)
        p <- p + geom_smooth()

   print(p)

   }, height=700)

 }

shinyApp(ui, tyrePlot, fuelPlot)
```

Comment: First of all You should have posted a sample data, it is actually impossible to run Your code without it...Without running Your code, i can just assume that the problem is: **the same name of plot:** `output$plotF` in your server (should not be `output$plotT` and `output$plotF`?)

Comment: ^ thanks for the reply, I should really have posted the solution to this problem, I will go digging in my repo. However, I did get around the issue with some help on the R-Studio forums, a quick search for anyone interested will find the answer. It was added a day or so after this post. Thanks.